# Batch file string variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why this is happening.  I'm sure it's a simple, stupid answer, but here goes.

```
    setlocal
set wimfile="dogs"
:wim_loop
dir n:\*.wim /b /a-d
echo.

set /p %wimfile%="Which wim to install? "
echo "%wimfile%"
```

I did an initial set of wimfile to *something* but it's not even echoing that.  When I run it, I get this:

[image]

This script successfully reads a variable from the command line, the server share to attach to.  It successfully reads a 'yes' from the user, to proceed (the portion that activates diskpart has been remmed out).  It lists the available wims.  Then it asks the user which wim, and the variable that was set to "dogs" (I've also tried this with "") is blank.  It's not the static set, it's not the dynamic set from the dialogue with the user.

(The wim_loop label is for a loop that should run until the user puts in a valid file name or elects to exit the batch.)

I don't get what's going wrong.  I apologize if it's some really easy syntax error, but a little help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: You do not use the percent symbols with the `SET` command to assign a value to a variable. `set /p wimfile="Which wim to install? "`

Comment: You should have echoed `%dogs%` to see what had been input.

Comment: The problem appears to be somewhere else in the script, so thanks for the attempted help.  When I deleted everything else but the portion causing a problem, my subscript works.  Weird.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your issue is, but I'm assuming that your last line, which would currently return `"dogs"` isn't what you wanted. What I think you wanted was to return the input added at the previous `Set /P` command. To do that you could either change your last line to `call echo "%%%wimfile%%%"` or you could delay the expansion by changing it to this instead, `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Echo "!%wimfile%!" & EndLocal`.